# What are there advantages to using Static Text instead of Label in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, label, static-text

From the [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Labels) for labels:

*You place a label on a form when you need to identify or annotate another component such as an edit box or when you want to include text on a form. The standard label component, TLabel, is a non-windowed control, so it cannot receive focus; when you need a label with a window handle, use TStaticText instead.*

What does the statement "***when you need a label with a window handle, use TStaticText instead***" mean?

Comment: Personally, I would highlight just the ability of having focus. I can't think of any practical reason to just *"have a label with a window handle"*. `TStaticText` can receive focus, so you can write keyboard handlers for it. You can then allow `TabStop` and you'll be able to focus the control and e.g. on a CTRL + C key press copy the content into the clipboard, or something (also, nothing what I would find somehow practical).

Comment: I like the ability to SetFocus.

Comment: Sometimes use of static text avoids resize flicker

Comment: But if I don't want to set focus on the StaticText then I can just set FocusControl to the Edit which is labeled by the StaticText. This means that the StaicText now works as a regular Label.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At work, we use a TStaticText when we want our UI automation testing tool to 'read' the text of a "label". Most of the interaction is done by Windows API messaging, so a TStaticText will respond to GetWindowText, while a TLabel will not. This is a simplistic overview on how we use TStaticText and a TLabel.

Answer (score 9):

Also, if you're creating forms that need to work with screen readers for visually impaired users, TLabels can't be seen by the software, but TStaticText labels can.

Comment: In addition to this, `TStaticText` labels need to use correct `TabOrder` (one before the control they are describing), and one super-important thing, this doesn't work for *NVDA* so you also have to place `TStaticText` right *AFTER* the control it describes in the *DFM* file by manually editing it. It took me tons of time to figure out that *NVDA* doesn't care about `TabOrder` but component creation order instead. Haven't tested in *Jaws* or other screenreaders though.

Answer (score 2):

Cut and pasted from [Embarcadero](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/StdCtrls_TStaticText.html)

> The TStaticText component functions like TLabel, except that it
>   descends from TWinControl and therefore has a window handle. Use
>   TStaticText instead of TLabel when the component's accelerator key
>   must belong to a windowed control—for example, on an ActiveX property
>   page.

Comment: copy and paste. you can't cut embarky.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason there are these two label controls with almost the same functionality is (pre)historical.

In old versions of Windows (old as Windows 3.x), there was a practical limit of number of handles the whole system could have. So using handle-less label control was good way to save these precious system resources. That's why Borland introduced the `TLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

**TStaticText**
TStaticText has a Window Handle and can accept focus whereas TLabel does not have a Window Handle and cannot accept focus

TStaticText allows the user to edit the text displayed whereas TLabel does not allow the user to edit the text displayed

**TLabel**
TLabel's caption property can be changed programmatically whereas TStaticText's Caption property cannot be changed programmatically

TLabel does not have a ShowAccelChar property whereas TStaticText does have a ShowAccelChar property